# What is causing a hyperlink to force a request without cookies?

Tags: html, content-security-policy

Here is the setup:

1. user authenticates on website example.org
2. user goes to stripe.com
3. user clicks a hyperlink that takes them back to example.org

At #3 I would expect user to load example.org as authenticated user, but in practice, the page is loaded without passing the session cookie.

> Note: If I just type example.org in the URL bar while on stripe.com, I am taken to example.org with the correct headers.

This is the header that I expect:

```
Cookie:
  ajs_user_id=1c18580e-ab01-46d1-93ca-1640f7c3aed4;
  ajs_anonymous_id=2e725e56-c57c-4fd5-8a27-cbf5ec476ca9; 
  Session=YVF2WTFCQUVMZDkyU3FqZVhodjVI.8YX7wNCVx5VxlG49J4jZvRgoA6GuLRhw57GqoMJk9s0;
  __stripe_mid=c0c74b2c-bc04-4e74-ac3d-e8de506d6169b50524;
  __stripe_sid=a9a68817-a16a-447c-84ee-b35e241cf784b4d998;
  foo_authenticated=true
```

This is the header that actually gets used:

```
Cookie:
  ajs_user_id=1c18580e-ab01-46d1-93ca-1640f7c3aed4;
  ajs_anonymous_id=2e725e56-c57c-4fd5-8a27-cbf5ec476ca9;
  foo_authenticated=true
```

So only *Session* cookie is not passed.

This is how example.org server sets `foo_authenticated` cookie:

```
set-cookie: foo_authenticated=true; Max-Age=86400; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

This is how example.org server sets `Session` cookie:

```
set-cookie: Session=YVF2WTFCQUVMZDkyU3FqZVhodjVI.8YX7wNCVx5VxlG49J4jZvRgoA6GuLRhw57GqoMJk9s0; Max-Age=2592000; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 21 Oct 2023 14:40:51 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
```

I was wondering if `SameSite=Strict` would have anything to do with it, but it does not seem to be the case, since in case of the hyperlink, the user is taken to example.org, i.e. it would be first-party cookie.

> If you set SameSite to Strict, your cookie will only be sent in a first-party context. In user terms, the cookie will only be sent if the site for the cookie matches the site currently shown in the browser's URL bar.

For what it is worth, these are the headers that Stripe sets:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Age: 31
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Security-Policy: base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://api.stripe.com https://errors.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com https://r.stripe.com https://checkout-cookies.stripe.com https://stripe.com/cookie-settings/enforcement-mode https://merchant-ui-api.stripe.com; default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com; form-action 'none'; frame-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com https://payments.stripe.com https://checkout.link.com; img-src 'self' https://q.stripe.com https://js.stripe.com https://stripe-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net https://d1wqzb5bdbcre6.cloudfront.net https://qr.stripe.com https://b.stripecdn.com; media-src 'none'; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com 'sha256-qfab1QOuLBUBGJ+fPSXEniBt3ROj7X2Q4d7JLWBSVcU=' 'sha256-+W3a2fgQuz1ZpIGnQMOq2JxsBWhMwNrxjhlii+QpWY0=' 'sha256-Z0881ecbuBTAbfxSpCkwHujx6fgI1J7PuSRWyTTP14I='; style-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com 'sha256-xFwBW6bBM1mbVaXYRj9IZq1/WXqmeNKvUIKHAh5RWrg='; report-uri https://q.stripe.com/csp-report
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 21 Sep 2023 14:43:10 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 22:11:19 GMT
Server: cloudflare
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 3d0244d93468697e8191825e8571d06c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: qS3zdvs1O6qO7kmo6C0FNy0F3qbLfTLOcxJEbQXzdu9IWReXXJkqEQ==
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: DFW57-P2
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Once again, nothing here catch my eyes too much.

There is also nothing special with the hyperlink:

```
<a class="Link Header-businessLink Link--primary" href="https://example.org/settings" aria-label="Back to Foo" title="Foo" target="_self">
```

It appears there is a header/html attribute or something else that I am unfamiliar with that is causing user going from stripe.com to example.org via a hyperlink to not send the cookie with `SameSite=Strict`. What is it and how do we mitigate it?

Here is a video demo showing step by step of what is happening: https://www.loom.com/share/e8efe137707548abb5be0d350097cbeb

For what it is worth, it appears like it is something that originates from stripe.com, i.e. something we have no control over. We are planning to workaround this by telling stripe.com to send users to `https://example.org/redirect?to=https://example.org/actual-destination`. However, I am still curious to know how stripe.com does it.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what SameSite=strict is supposed to to:

Comparing the possible values for SameSite in [MDN Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie):

> Strict
>
> Means that the browser sends the cookie only for same-site requests, that is, requests originating from the same site that set the cookie. If a request originates from a different domain or scheme (even with the same domain), no cookies with the SameSite=Strict attribute are sent.

> Lax
>
> Means that the cookie is not sent on cross-site requests, such as on requests to load images or frames, but is sent when a user is navigating to the origin site from an external site (for example, when following a link). This is the default behavior if the SameSite attribute is not specified.

it follows that the request initiated by clicking the link to example.com on stripe.com is considered cross origin.
So you should use `SameSite=Lax` for this purpose, or trigger another page load when coming from extern. (you could detect this using one SameSite=Strict and one SameSite=Lax cookie)

Comment: I was going to rebut your claim, but I was able to replicate it. This is bizarre and unexpected though. I would expect that a hyperlink click is not considered a cross-site request. This is just user navigating from one page to another.

Comment: @Gajus — It mitigates CSRF attacks.

Comment: I am struggling to follow what kind of attack could this mitigate, and also what is the proper solution. If we added `https://example.org/redirect?to=` as a general purpose utility to our function, wouldn't the third-party site be able to execute exactly the same attack vector as if `SameSite` was set to `Lax`?

Comment: "I am struggling to follow what kind of attack could this mitigate" — Any [CSRF attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) that depends on the cookie credentials to get authorisation.

Comment: "If we added https://example.org/redirect?to= as a general purpose utility to our function, wouldn't the third-party site be able to execute exactly the same attack vector as if SameSite was set to Lax?" — Well, hopefully you're not doing a 307 or 308 redirect with that and not doing anything vulnerable on a GET request … but generally when you write hacks to bypass security features then you weaken security.

Comment: so how do sites like LinkedIn make the auth work? if I use URL like <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">airbnb</a>, it takes me to authenticated state

Comment: TLDR is that those sites like LinkedIn, Airbnb, Facebook, etc all use Lax, but they use nonce for all their forms.

Comment: the token used for forms originates in sad old times where the behavior of SameSite=None was the default (i.e. pre 2020 :)). If they weren't out of date browsers, you could go without it. When POSTing using forms or fetch (as nobody would ever change state with a GET :)), the cookie is not sent with SameSite=Lax